Certificateless public key cryptography
In the Wikipedia article on Certificateless Public Key Cryptography https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificateless_cryptography, it states, "For tight security, a certificateless system has to prove its security against two types of adversaries. Type 1 Adversary- Refers to any third party who can fake the user's public keys, corresponding to obtaining the user's random secret value." Does this mean that a Type 1 adversary has access to the user's random secret value?

Not necessarily.  If we read the Cetificateless public key paper of Al-Riyami and Paterson, we see in the introduction to section 3 at the head of page 9 that (full) private keys $S_A$ are produced as a function of partial private keys $D_A$ and random secret values $x_A$. We also see that public keys $P_A$ depend on $x_A$ but can be verified without knowledge of $x_A$.
In section 3.1 on page 11, we see that a type I adversary can, for identities of its choice (with certain restrictions)

request public keys $P_A$
replace public keys with (valid) values $P'_A$ of their choice
extract partial private keys $D_A$
extract private keys $S_A$
make decryption queries

none of these a priori provides the adversary with knowledge of $x_A$.

In a certificateless signature scheme's security model involving a Type 1 adversary and a challenger, the process unfolds in three phases:  In first phase, the adversary can request Partial private key, Secret key, Private key, Public key for any user with an identity. In challenge phase, the adversary outputs the identity of the challenger and two messages. The challenger selects one of these messages, produces a signature for it, and sends it to the adversary.

In last phase, the adversary must determine which of the two messages corresponds to the signature provided by the challenger with the restrictions that the adversary cannot query the partial private key or the private key for the challenger's identity,  the sign query for the specific message used in the challenge. However, the adversary can request the secret key for the challenger’s identity, which corresponds to having access to the user's secret value. Is my understanding wrong?

Also, in this paper link, page 3, it is mentioned that a type 1 adversary is permitted to retrieve user's secret value.
